# how to easily get current size of bootstrap responsive button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some code like the below that creates a button that continuously varies in size according to screen size (because of "img-responsive").

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block img-responsive" id="btntest" href="#" role="button" onclick="showWidth()">{{button.label}}</a>
```

I have another element on the screen that I want to force to be the same size as the arbitrary button size.  I need to determine the button size and set the size of the other element the same.  I have tried the below as a start to getting the size but it just displays an empty string.  Any ideas?

```
//in css file
#btntest{display : inline-block;}
~~~~~~~
//in angular controller
showWidth = function() {
var e = document.getElementById("btntest");
console.log(e.style.width);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include the jquery library:

```
<script src="...path to jquery.js in your website or use CDN" />
```

then use this:

```
$("#btntest").width()
```